# IIS Remote Administration via a Website

Tags: iis

Are there any products available in IIS7.5 that allow Administration of IIS (Application Pools, Virtual Directories, e.g.: using System.DirectoryServices) via a Website?

Something that I can put Windows Auth on and not have to login to the machine to administer / setup new applications?

I have not found anything online & my Google-foo may be growing weaker...

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are looking for a Windows equivalent to Webmin, however there are some potential other solutions too.  Keep in mind a preference for strong authentication too!  Enough with the caveats, here are some methods.

**Remote display method over HTTP/S**

**client** -HTTP/HTTPS-  **Server** -remote display protocol- **Server**

You can install the RDP Active X control in order to do that.

Furthermore, you can use RDP competitors that have HTTP or HTTPS interfaces such as VNC and *VNC variants

Other options embeddable in webpages such as Citrix, and other protocols are options too.

**Scriptable webshells**

You can use Windows 8 web based powershell, IPSweb, WebPSconsole, and numerous java applets, however, I don't think that is what you are looking for based on your comments.

**Web based administration tools specific to hosting environments**

This category opens up tools like Plesk, Webmin (limited Windows support), H-Sphere, Hosting Controller, and Cpanel (believe Windows support is in beta).  Openpanel and others are heading towards windows support too.  I think this category of tools best meets your stated requirements and is fertile ground for an analysis of alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, Brennan -- I'm more interested in something purely web-based that does not rely on RDP/VNC.  It's possibly programmatically so I assumed something would exist.

Comment: The web UIs that I mentioned are actually purely web-based from a client perspective (HTTP or HTTPS).  The server - server communications, would of course use a display protocol of one type or another.